# Integral involving Marcum Q-function

Tags: special-functions

I'm struggling to find an approximation for the following integral:

> $$\int\limits_0^\infty  {{{\left[ {1 - Q\left( {a\sqrt t ,b} \right)} \right]}^n}{e^{ - t}}dt} $$

where ${Q\left( {a\sqrt t ,b} \right)}$ is the first order Marcum Q-function.

Do you have any idea how to do it? 
Thank you.

Comment: Does this function come from statistics?

Comment: The function comes from a communication system performance analysis.

Comment: You have not said anything about $n$!

Comment: n is greater than 2.

Comment: @BBinh: approximation in what sense!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal:
$a = \sqrt {\frac{{2\rho }}{{1 - \rho }}}$ and $b = \sqrt {\frac{{2{\gamma _0}}}{{\lambda \left( {1 - \rho } \right)}}}$.

($0 < \rho < 1$, and $\gamma_0$ is a constant). I want to find an approximation when $\lambda$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Does your $Q$ stands for $Q_1$?

Comment: Yes, it is. ^^^